# should I be worried about this...?

Tags: ssh, rsa, git-remote

I tried pushing onto a git repo on my server, so I thought I did something like this

```
git remote add games@games.com
```

When I should have done

```
git remote add games@gamesThatAreFunEtc.com
```

Anyway I thought it was weird that it asked for my password but not realizing what was happening I gave it. I think the site also got my private key as it probably tried to use my key in `~/.ssh` first.

Should I now change my password and/or rsa key? Does doing something like that log an incorrect password attempt with the incorrect pass or the rsa key? Should I worry that if it does, the owner of the site will try to break into my site?

Also as it's not obvious from the login attempt what my site name actually is, am I fretting for nothing? Can I assume he won't try every combination of domains that start with `games`

Comment: If your worried, then just change it. No harm can come of changing it right?

Comment: @annonymously: well the complexity of changing it is `O(n^4)` for n users of that account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's good that you noticed your error and that you care enough to ask this question here. I'd assume most people would get back to business and not worry.

- your RSA key is safe, as it is only used in a challenge-response query to verify if it matches any saved public keys, it is not transmitted to the server
- you should change your password, as a malicious server could have logged it

You probably don't have to worry about the owner of the site breaking into yours. Usually ssh-server do not log passwords. I would change my password anyway, just to be safe.

In the future, try to heed the warnings ssh gives you (in your case probably a missing `known_hosts` entry) and take them seriously instead of mindlessly pressing 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As pointed out, since you entered your password when connecting to the unknown site, change it.

As to your private key, its fine as long as it doesn't share the same password - at most the remote site would have got a sniff of your public key only, your intended username, and ip your were using.  The likelihood that someone at that address is actively monitoring the single 'failed connection' log line, or doing anything insidious is very, very, very small.

If you need more encouragement, and want more information about how such transactions typically go down, google "diffie/hellman key exchange".

Comment: I think your advice is somewhat dangerous. It is possible to log ssh passwords (which @qwertymk apparently sent to the server), so he should definitely change it.

Comment: Ah, yes, never noticed that he entered his password, so best to change it, although the chances that picking a random domain name to connect to, and discovering that it belongs to someone harvesting wrong password attempts is pretty slim.  But judge by the potential consequences, not the likelihood, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. It's probably more probable to be struck by lightning, but it's also much easier to guard yourself in the password case :)